# Month by month rolling CV in mlr3

Tags: r, cross-validation, mlr3

My goal is to create Resampling using `mlr3` package that uses some sort of rolling CV. More concretely, I want to use n months of data in training set (say 6 months) and one month of data in test set.

Here is example of my data set:

```
DT <- structure(list(Not_FLS_positive = c(0.408197129345391, 0.765784452003651, 
                                          0.44694266987472, 0.261843524433751, 0.823612378660914, 0.463701982908819, 
                                          0.50286235791919, 0.202937028125778, 0.728864183190907, 0.396498796980005, 
                                          0.0645482452501452, 0.386210901850162, 0.518874968887414, 0.748527337592301, 
                                          0.453414087778976, 0.758566332033519, 0.544926574296856, 0.758151497552477, 
                                          0.641583008379657, 0.15000414834481, 0.271384717497718, 0.516634862689787, 
                                          0.379988384634531, 0.220277109433336, 0.368373019165353, 0.367294449514644, 
                                          0.924583091346553, 0.702895544677674, 0.560192483199204, 0.61212976022567, 
                                          0.0189164523355181, 0.308139052518045), Not_FLS_negative = c(0.690284576453995, 
                                                                                                       0.406288890732598, 0.965402804281092, 0.981830249730358, 0.750850410686136, 
                                                                                                       0.884676014270306, 0.978760474570646, 0.846013440637186, 0.319754417987223, 
                                                                                                       0.70256367709284, 0.0308636853895296, 0.247905085870738, 0.886999087364142, 
                                                                                                       0.28017920849581, 0.697253795735502, 0.720069692192815, 0.838131585497387, 
                                                                                                       0.967559943582511, 0.755745457562433, 0.97593960009956, 0.886833153571725, 
                                                                                                       0.587156724466938, 0.959097320169252, 0.0548411183937609, 0.957769849829918, 
                                                                                                       0.479382726292209, 0.626897867750767, 0.772670704388949, 0.9822450842114, 
                                                                                                       0.736829005226914, 0.420642163776653, 0.723886169418402), bin_aroundzero_ret_excess_stand_22 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "1", "-1"), class = "factor"), monthid = c("20141", "20141", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "20141", "20141", "20141", "20141", "20141", "20141", "20141", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "20141", "20142", "20142", "20142", "20142", "20142", "20142", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "20142", "20142", "20142", "20142", "20142", "20143", "20143", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "20143", "20143", "20143", "20143", "20143", "20143", "20143", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "20143", "20143")), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "data.frame"))
```

Now, I want to use months 20141 and 20142 in train set and 20143 in the test set. I thougt the best way is to set monthid group role:

```
task <- as_task_classif(DT, id = "aroundzero", target = "bin_aroundzero_ret_excess_stand_22")
task$set_col_roles("monthid", "group")
```

and now use `ResamplingRollingWindowCV` from `mlr3temporal` package:

```
resampling = rsmp("forecast_cv", folds = 5, fixed_window = TRUE, horizon = 1L, window_size = 6)
resampling$instantiate(task)
```

but this return an error:

```
Error in max(ids) - self$param_set$values$horizon : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I have then tried to use custom resampling:

```
custom = rsmp("custom")
train_sets = list(1:2)
test_sets = list(3)
custom$instantiate(task, train_sets, test_sets)
custom$train_set(1)
custom$test_set(1)
```

but this returns only 1,2 in train and 3 in test set. It seems it does't use groups bt individual observations.
Is it possible to vreate my by month rolling cv in current Resampling scheme or should I create completely new class for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping is not supported by `ResamplingForecastCV`. You could try [Leave-time-out resampling](https://mlr3spatiotempcv.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_resamplings_sptcv_cstf.html) and tag `monthid` with the `"time"` row role. But with this method you also predict months in the past e.g. training set is `20143` and `20142` and test set is `20141`. If that's not working for you, you need to use `ResamplingCustom`.

> this returns only 1,2 in train and 3 in test set

This is the correct behavior. You pass the row ids of the task. You have to do the grouping yourself before and pass the grouped IDs to the resampling.

**Update**

With you data:

```r
custom = rsmp("custom")
train_sets = list(1:21)
test_sets = list(22:32)
custom$instantiate(task, train_sets, test_sets)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try LTO CV, but if months go in past that mean I just have to order ascending before creating the task? 
Custom CV- I have done grouping with `task$set_col_roles("monthid", "group")`. I have groupids. How can I provide groupids to resampling? i don't see any argument to `ResamplingCustom$new()`.

Comment: If I want to use `ResamplingForecastCV`, I need to set coordinates when defining task which I don't have or need.

Comment: Please read the documentation of `ResamplingCustom` again. You can freely design the resampling splits. You pass row ids to the resampling. There is no grouping option. You have to do the grouping yourself. Sorry about LTO. I thought this one works without coordinates.

Comment: See the update. If your data set is large you have to programmatically solve this.

Comment: I have create custom CV's by myself. I encounter another problem, becaue sustom CV's doesnt't work with 'auto_tuner', but this is another issue...

Comment: Glad it worked. The latest [mlr3tuning version 0.17.2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr3tuning/news/news.html) supports `AutoTuner` with custom cv.